How do I use a fetch response object with fluent-ffmpeg?
The following code throws an error:
async start(url, user = null, pass = null) {
            console.log('Transcoding:', url);
            const headers = {};

            try {
                if (user && pass) {
                    const encodedCredentials = Buffer.from(`${user}:${pass}`).toString('base64');
                    headers['Authorization'] = `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`;
                }

                // Fetch the video from the URL
                const response = await fetch(url, { headers, redirect: 'follow' });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch video: ${response.statusText}`);
                }

                // Create a readable stream from the response
                // const videoStream = response.body;
                const videoStream = response.body;

                console.log(videoStream);

                // Ensure videoStream is a valid readable stream
                if (!videoStream) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to get video stream from response');
                }

                // Create a pass-through stream to handle ffmpeg output
                const outputStream = new PassThrough();

                // Pipe the video stream through ffmpeg to transcode it to mp4
                ffmpeg(videoStream)
                    .format('mp4')
                    // .output(outputStream)
                    .videoCodec('libx264')
                    .audioCodec('aac')
                    .on('start', (commandLine) => {
                        console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
                    })
                    .on('error', (err) => {
                        console.error('Error:', err.message);
                        console.error(err);
                        outputStream.destroy(err); // destroy the stream in case of error
                    })
                    .on('progress', (progress) => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(progress, null, 2));
                        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
                    })
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('Transcoding finished');
                    })
                    .pipe(outputStream);

                return outputStream;
            } catch (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        }

Here's the error message:
Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 pipe:1
{
  "frames": 0,
  "currentFps": 0,
  "currentKbps": null,
  "targetSize": 0,
  "timemark": "N/A"
}
Processing: undefined% done
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 234: Conversion failed!

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 234: Conversion failed!

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ettinger/src/watch.theater/watchtheater-web/node_modules/.pnpm/fluent-ffmpeg@2.1.3/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:180:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

I'm trying to stream the output in real-time without having to download the entire video file first.

I got it working with @rcompat library on npm:
import file from "@rcompat/fs/file";
import { mp4 } from "@rcompat/http/mime";
import spawn from "@rcompat/stdio/spawn";

const command = "ffmpeg";
const input = "-i pipe:0";
const flags = "-acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov";
const output = "-f mp4 pipe:1";
const repo = "primatejs/guides";
const url = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${repo}/ffmpeg/assets/test.avi`;

export default {
  async get(request) {
    const { stdout, stdin } = spawn(`${command} ${input} ${flags} ${output}`);

    (await fetch(url)).body.pipeTo(stdin);

    return new Response(stdout, { headers: { "content-type": mp4 }});
  }
}



https://raw.githubusercontent.com/primatejs/guides/ffmpeg/routes/index.js
